# PHP Convert New Line in Textarea to <BR>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a data.txt file that posts what is in it from a textarea to an HTML page with PHP.

I want the text area to read new lines as a `<br>` element so it all isn't on the same line when I make a new line.

Example:

```
Hello
Hello
```

equals

```
HelloHello
```

but I want it to equal

```
Hello
Hello
```

I have already tried implementing `n2lbr` but it is hard to implement with my system so if you are going to suggest that please show how.

SO here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <form method="POST" action="process.php" onsubmit='return validate ()' > 
    <textarea cols='60' rows='8' id="input1" type="text" name="myInputName" style="background:white;border:2px solid #dfdfdf;color:black;height:50px;"></textarea> 

    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Post" style="width:60px;height:55px;background:white;color:black;border:2px solid #dfdfdf;" class="cbutton" /> 
  </form> 

  <form method="POST" action="clear.php">
    <input type="submit" name="Clear" value="Erase" style="width:265px;height:30px;background:white;color:black;border:2px solid #dfdfdf;margin-top:2px;" class="cbutton"/>
  </form>
</div>
<p style="font-size:35px;text-align:center;font-family:Raleway;">To do List</p>
<div id="list2" style="">

<?php
  $myfilename = "data.txt";
  if (file_exists($myfilename)) {
    echo file_get_contents($myfilename);
    nl2br($myfilename);
  }
?>
```

PHP (PROCESS.PHP):

```
<?php 
  // We will put the data into a file in the current directory called "data.txt" 
  // But first of all, we need to check if the user actually pushed submit 

  if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) { 

    // The user clicked submit 
    // Put the contents of the text into the file 
    file_put_contents('./data.txt', $_POST['myInputName'] . '</br>', FILE_APPEND);
    $str = $_POST["myInputName"] echo nl2br($str);

    // ./data.txt: the text file in which the data will be stored 
    // $_POST['myInputName']: What the user put in the form field named "myInputName" 
    // FILE_APPEND: This tells the function to append to the file and not to overwrite it. 
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Have had a ton of trouble with this.

Comment: in your html your echoing the file contents outside of the textarea - so that's never going to work. your also applying nl2br to the file name, not the contents.

Comment: can't you just do `echo nl2br(file_get_contents($myfilename))` ?

Comment: I will try right now. I have tried everything I can think of so it being outside of the textarea was probably me just experimenting with everything else I could think of.

Comment: nothing works, so for now I am just looking for a new way/new script even if it involves n2lbr again. not looking for revisions.

Answer (score 1):

You're not echoing the result of `nl2br()`, you're just echoing the original contents of the file, then calling `nl2br()` and ignoring what it returns. It should be:

```
echo nl2br(file_get_contents($myfilename));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use PHP's built-in function: `nl2br()` and that should do it like so:

```
  <?php
      $stringFromTextArea = "The Quick brown Fox\nStumble upon\nA Bag of Worms\n";
      $stringWithBR       = nl2br($stringFromTextArea);
      echo $stringWithBR;
```

This same function could still be used for a Contents sifted using `file_get_contents()` like so:

```
  <?php
      $stringFromFile     = file_get_contents($pathToFile);
      $stringWithBR       = nl2br($stringFromFile);
      echo $stringWithBR;
```